# Lombok @SuperBuilder is not initializing my class objects

Tags: java, spring, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have a parent class and a child class and I am using `@SuperBuilder` to build the child object, but seemingly it is not initializing at all.
My parent class looks like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@SuperBuilder
public class MessageResponse {
    String responseMessage;
}
```

My child class looks like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@SuperBuilder
public class ListResponse extends MessageResponse {
    List<Item> itemList;
    int itemCount;
}
```

Where *Item* is a `Serializable` class.

Initially the `ListResponse` is

```
itemList = null
itemCount = 0
responseMessage = null
```

When I try to build `ListResponse` using builder, it does not change the `ListResponse` object at all. I am trying to build as

```
//listResponse is @Autowired from Spring and is initially as shown above. 
List<Item> itemList = getItems(); // It returns a list of 15 items, i have checked in debugger, It does.
listResponse.builder()
        .bucketList(itemList)
        .responseMessage("Item List.")
        .bucketCount(itemList.size())
        .build();
```

Even after execution of `.build()` the contents of this `listResponse` object is still `(null, 0 , null)`.

I tried to search other references regarding `@SuperBuilder` and `@Builder` but got no result. Can someone please point out what is going wrong here?

Comment: @altarbza Thanks, but can you please help to solve the problem in hand first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A builder always creates a new instance. This is the purpose of the builder pattern, and it is how builders work, whether you use Lombok's `@SuperBuilder`, `@Builder`, or a manual builder implementation.

You can see that the `builder()` method is a `static` method, so it has no access to the instance (typically your IDE should give you a warning here, advising to write `ListResponse.builder()` instead).

If you want to create a new instance using a builder that is pre-filled with the fields from an existing instance, you can use `toBuilder = true` as annotation parameter on `@(Super)Builder`. Then call `listResponse.toBuilder()`.

If you want to modify an instance, the builder pattern is not the right choice. Use setters instead. Those can be generated by Lombok also in a fluent, chainable style; see `@Accessors` for details.